# Anaconda: "conda update conda" issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, anaconda

Having difficulties after installing Anaconda 1.9.2 Windows x86-64 on Windows 7 (64-bit).

I already had an install of Python 2.7, so I installed for All Users. I selected "Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable", but I did not select "Register Anaconda as my default Python 2.7".

Install was successful , but upon attempting to run (as Administrator) "conda update conda" and "conda update ipython" I'm getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 2 in 
       from conda.cli import main
ImportError: No module named conda.cli.

I did a system search and I can't find a single instance of conda.cli on my machine, is there some way the install would've missed this file, or is there something else I should have installed? I've seen this question involving 64-bit Linux Anaconda, but not Windows.

Comment: `conda.cli` is a Python module name, not a file - the file will probably be called `conda\cli.py`, or it might be a folder, `conda\cli`.

Comment: Do you have PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME set from the other installation?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have this folder in your system: C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli'. 
Also please try to check your python path and attach the logs:

```
(TEST) C:\anaconda3\Scripts>python
Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 12:30:02) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import os
>>> print(os.sys.path)
['', 'C:\\anaconda3\\envs\\TEST\\python36.zip', 'C:\\anaconda3\\envs\\TEST\\DLLs', 'C:\\anaconda3\\envs\\TEST\\lib', 'C:\\anaconda3\\envs\\TEST', 'C:\\anaconda3\\envs\\TEST\\lib\\site-packages']
```